# SBT - Is there a way to ignore duplicate mappings in copyResources?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am trying to generate a fat jar using SBT and sbt-assembly. As a requirement, there are other unmanaged resources (directories) that I need to add in the jar. The problem is there are files on 2 directories that have the same file name and path. So running ***assembly*** results to a copyResources error - a Duplicate Mappings error. The behaviour that I want is if the file is already existing, discard the other file. Is there a way to do this? Will this work?

```
unmanagedResources in Compile ~= (_.distinct)
```

Is it a solution? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the assembly plugin's [merge strategy settings](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#merge-strategy) are sufficient for you. Try this:

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) => {
  case PathList("path", "to", "file", xs @ _*) =>
    (xs map {_.toLowerCase}) match {
      case ("myduplicatefile" :: Nil) => MergeStrategy.first
      case _ => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
    }
  case x => old(x)
}
```