# Duplicate mappings error when running test command in SBT on task test:copyResources

Tags: sbt

I have a test-suite that contains several files and folders with test data. Some of the files have repeated names in different folders.

In SBT I have a task to generate the resources downloading the resources and uncompressing them in a folder.

The build.sbt file (simplified) is:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

resourceGenerators in Test += Def.task {
  val shaclTests = url("https://github.com/w3c/data-shapes/raw/gh-pages/data-shapes-test-suite/tests.zip")
  IO.unzipURL(shaclTests, resourceManaged.value / "test-suite" ).toSeq
 }.taskValue
```

when I execute `sbt test` I obtain:

```
[error] (test:copyResources) Duplicate mappings:
[error]         C:\src\pruebas\duplicates-sbt\target\scala-2.10\test-classes\manifest.ttl
[error] from
[error]         C:\src\pruebas\duplicates-sbt\target\scala-2.10\resource_managed\test-suite\tests\manifest.ttl
...
```

which complains that the `manifest.ttl` file is duplicated.

If I remove the duplicated files it works, however, I think it should be possible to have duplicate file names in different folders.

I have found some related issue [here](https://github.com/eamelink/sbt-purescript/pull/15) but although I tried to use `crossTarget` instead of `resourceManaged` it still doesn't work.

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037395/sbt-is-there-a-way-to-ignore-duplicate-mappings-in-copyresources) that may be related, but it is about generating assemblies and the solution doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: The files are indeed copied to target even though the task fails. I get the feeling this is some sort of SBT bug.

Comment: Yes, the files are copied but the target stops and doesn't let me continue with the tests. I have filed [this issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2047)

Comment: I did try to find a way to continue even though a task fails, but I wasn't able to get that working ... I think it's a good idea to raise the bug. I am sure it's a problem from their side.